# Removing the first lines of multiple records in an RTF Long Text field in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to remove the first few lines of multiple records in a Rich Text Long Text field in access? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you can, as you can do many string manipulations in Access.
Try to show some research and attempts next time.

You can use the following function to remove lines from strings:

```
Public Function RemoveLines(str As String, LineCount As Integer) As String
    Dim searchPosition As Integer
    searchPosition = 1
    Dim linesPassed As Integer
    linesPassed = 0
    Dim Found As Integer
    Found = 1
    Do While linesPassed < LineCount
        Found = InStr(searchPosition, str, vbCrLf)
        If Found <> 0 Then
            searchPosition = Found + 2
        Else
            RemoveLines = ""
            Exit Function
        End If
        linesPassed = linesPassed + 1
    Loop
    RemoveLines = Mid(str, searchPosition)
End Function
```

This removes `LineCount` lines from your string. You can either use it in VBA or in action queries, though rich text memo fields in action queries tend to start with a single linebreak, and have all line breaks repeated. If you just enter twice the amount you actually want to remove, it will work in action queries.

Comment: Great. Thank you.